# Dividing a disk into two identical non-intersecting pieces?

Tags: geometry

I want to split an Euclidean disk (it should make no difference whether it's open or closed) into two non-intersecting sets of points which are identical in a sense that one set can be transformed into another (and vice versa) by using only shift and rotation.

Can that be done?

Comment: don't understand the question what is wrong by just cutting the disk by any diameter, then mirroring over this line swaps the sets, the same for rotating a half circle over the midpoint. (Guess i aam overlooking something fundamental here)

Comment: because when you cut the disk along the diameter, the diameter itself has to go to one of the parts(since the two parts are non-intersecting) so the two parts will be non equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Let $D$ be the (open, closed or whatever) unit disk and let $T\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be a rotation or trnslation such that $D=A\cup T[A]$ for some set $A$ with $A\cap T[A]=\emptyset$.
If $T[\partial D]=\partial D$, the point $0$ must be a fixed point of $T$; but then $0\in A$ implies $0=T(0)\in B$ and vice versa, contradiction.
Hence $T[\partial D]\ne \partial D$, i.e. these two circles intersect in two distinct points $a,b$.
Let $C_a$, $C_b$ be the circles through $a,b$ around the center of rotation (whch is on the line $ab$) - or in case of a translation the lines orthogonal to $ab$ through $a, b$, respectively.
These circles/lines intersect (not touch) $\partial D$, hence chop the interior of $D$ into three parts with nonempty interior. For the two "outer" parts we have that their images under $T$ are disjoint from $D$, hence thy must be $\subseteq B$. But they are also disjoint from $T[D]$ hence must be $\subseteq A$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible for closed disks. Say it is possible and you can divide the disk into two parts which are non-intersecting(say $A$ and $B$) and one can be transformed into another (and vice versa) by using only shift and rotation . Use the transformations 
$$g_1:A \rightarrow B $$
$$g_2:B \rightarrow A $$
Extend them to $\Bbb R^2$ call the extensions $g_1'$ and $ g_2'$.This can be done because they are given to be composition shifts and rotations. Now $g_1'og_2'$ and $g_2'og_1'$ are both $identity$. Hence $g_1og_2$ and $g_2og_1$ are both $identity$. The extension of $g_1$ to the disk will have no fixed point. This is a contradiction to brouwer's fixed point thoerem.

For any other disk use a similar proof on the closure of the disk.

Comment: If $D=A\cup B$ with $B=f[A]$, this does not easily give us $f\colon D\to D$.

Comment: f is a bijective function

Comment: $f$ needs to be defined in the first place.

Comment: Yes you are right its not that easy to extend.I edited the solution.It's completely different though

Comment: $g_1$ will not necessarily map $D\to D$. NB, we *can* find *continuous* maps $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ such that the open disk $D=A\cup f[A]$ and $A\cap f[A]=\emptyset$

Comment: $g_1$ is defined from $A$ to $B$ only and $g_1$ can be extended to the whole disk because $g_1'$ takes $B$ to $A$.

Comment: But this is not true when $f$ is assumed to be shifts and rotations right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a(n over-complicated) proof which does not appeal the classification of plane isometries.

**Proposition:** The unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be partitioned into two disjoint congruent subsets.

**Proof:** Let $D$ be the (open, closed, whatever) unit disk, and suppose there is a partition $D = X \coprod Y$ into two pieces $X$ and $Y$ that are congruent by an isometry $f: X \to Y$. Denoting the center of the disk by $p \in D$, assume without loss of generality that $p \in X$.

Since $f(p) \not\in X$, we know $f(p) \neq p$, hence $r:= d(p, f(p))> 0$.

*Claim:* For any $\epsilon \in (0,2)$, there are points $x$, $y\in X$ with $d(x,y) \ge 2-\epsilon$.

*Proof:* Assume not. Then $m:= \text{diam}(X) = \text{diam}(Y) < 2$. Denote by $A(r,s)$ the open annulus centered at $p$ with inner radius $r$ and outer radius $s$.

Let $x\in A(m/2, 1) \cap X$. Since $d(x,-x) > m$, it must be the case that some small neighborhood $N$ of $-x$ is contained in $Y$. However, for any $y \in N$, the same argument implies $-y \in X$; hence $-N \subset X$. Thus, $X \cap A(m/2, 1]$ is open in $A(m/2, 1)$.

Similarly, it's true that $Y \cap A(m/2,1)$ is open in $A(m/2,1)$. But this gives the connected set $A(m/2,1)$ a decomposition $$A(m/2,1) = (X \cap A(m/2,1)) \cup (Y \cap A(m/2, 1))$$ into disjoint open subsets. $\blacksquare$

One can easily compute that $$\text{diam}(D \cap f(D)) = \sqrt{4-r^2} < 2.$$ From the claim above, there are points $x, y \in X$ such that $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x,y) > \sqrt{4-r^2}$. But $f(x), f(y) \in D \cap f(D)$, contradiction. $\blacksquare$